# navigateTo doesn't work on Nativescript-Vue

Tags: nativescript, router

I saw several Stackoverflow questions about this but I still couldn't solve my problem about switching pages.

I import the second Vue page. Then I call this.$navigateTo() on the page I imported. I don't get any errors after executing the method. Nothing happens! The method gets executed but the page doesn't change. The path to the second page is valid.

```
import SecondPage from './SecondPage';   
export default {
  methods: {
    run(){
      console.log('test')
      this.$navigateTo(SecondPage)
    }
  }
}
```

this is the way I call the method:

```
<Button text="Check" @tap="run()" />
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is likely an error in the `SecondPage.vue` file. What you can try is change the `$navigateTo` call to have a catch statement:

```js
import SecondPage from './SecondPage';   
export default {
  methods: {
    run(){
      console.log('test')
      this.$navigateTo(SecondPage).catch(err => console.log('There was an error!', err))
    }
  }
}
```

See if it gives you a clue what might be wrong.

And just to make sure, `SecondPage` is indeed a `<Page>` component? (the root element is the Page?)

Comment: It was an error that came up on the second page. That's why it didn't get loaded all the time. Wow. So many hours wasted on nothing. Thank you very much!!